# what does this ssh command mean?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

Its an answer I got from questioning about port forwarding but I'm not sure what it means..

```
$ ssh lab_desktop -L 2200:lab_server:22 -vvv
```

my wild guess:

first get connect to lab_desktop
and then again log into lab_server(port 22) and the received data from this connection will be forwarded to lab_desktop, port 2200.

is my wild guess right??

but I still don't understand what that '-vvv' means...

---

update after applying answer:

okay with creek's helpful answer&comments, I did what I can to make creek's answer work

again, let me be clear with the terminologies

`mypc` - the one that's doing all the typing

`lab_desktop` - ssh server

`lab_server` - final destination that I want to communicate with. This server will only allow connection from `lab_desktop`. And one more thing: it will only allow connections through port 122.

okay since logging in to `lab_desktop` and `lab_server` requires username and password, I just made rsa authentication for `mypc`--`lab_desktop`  and `lab_desktop`--`lab_server` so that I wouldn't confront the trouble of entering the password all the time and just to set aside the possibility of password entering making the ssh command more complex.

After that I used the command:

`ssh Black@lab_desktop -v -L 2200:lab_server:122`

the below is the output

```
chulhyun@chulhyun-Inspiron-3420:~/.ssh$ ssh Black@$labcom -v -L 2200:143.248.146.204:122 
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 143.248.143.198 [143.248.143.198] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/chulhyun/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chulhyun/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chulhyun/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chulhyun/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chulhyun/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/chulhyun/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 79:64:5d:e7:ac:78:b7:52:3d:9a:6a:3b:c1:37:a0:2d
debug1: Host '143.248.143.198' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/chulhyun/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/chulhyun/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 143.248.143.198 ([143.248.143.198]:22).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:2200 forwarded to remote address 143.248.146.204:122
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 2200.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 2200.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = ko_KR.UTF-8
Last login: Tue Jun 24 16:47:27 2014 from 143.248.244.12

Black@Black-PC ~
$
```

its long but I guess the only thing that I should be looking is the lines:

```
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:2200 forwarded to remote address 143.248.146.204:122
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 2200.
```

when I use my netstat to see if this is true(`netstat -tulpn | grep 2200`) the output is :

```
root@chulhyun-Inspiron-3420:/etc/ssh# netstat -tulpn | grep 2200
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2200          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14966/ssh       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:2200                :::*                    LISTEN      14966/ssh
```

so I guess the ssh hopping is established after all..

The problem now is when I try to use the port 2200 in `mypc`. As Creek suggested, I need to exploit this port so I tried logging in with both my root account and user account but the result was a failure due to password..

```
chulhyun@chulhyun-Inspiron-3420:~$ su
password: 
root@chulhyun-Inspiron-3420:/home/chulhyun# ssh root@localhost -p 2200
root@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@localhost's password: 

root@chulhyun-Inspiron-3420:/home/chulhyun# exit
exit
chulhyun@chulhyun-Inspiron-3420:~$ ssh chulhyun@localhost -p 2200
chulhyun@localhost's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

The passwords are the right ones I'm sure of it. But I don't understand why it won't work...

I come up to this point. Could you help be reach further?

---

update

the new problem that I'm facing is discussed and solved at: [Linux can't recognize the right password when ssh'ing?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138886/linux-cant-recognize-the-right-password-when-sshing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ssh lab_desktop -L 2200:lab_server:22 -vvv`

1. `ssh lab_desktop` - create an ssh connection to `lab_desktop` as `$USER`
2. `-L 2200:lab_server:22` - using the connection to `lab_desktop`, forward port 2200 on the local machine to port 22 on `lab_server`
3. `-vvv` - enable the maximum verbosity level

---

This command will open a socket on your local machine on port 2200, then using an SSH tunnel, all traffic sent to port 2200 on localhost will be FORWARDED to port 22 on lab_server.

To utilize your forwarded port and establish an SSH connection to lab_server, you'll need to initiate a second connection where you connect to the local port on localhost:

```
ssh user@localhost -p 2200
```

Comment: at '2.' what does it mean 'foward port 2200 on local machine to port 22 of lab_server?? at this point does local machine=lab_desktop or localhost(the computer that I'll be typing into)?

Comment: local machine = the machine you initiated the connection from, e.g. localhost

Comment: when I'm logging in to `lab_desktop` and `lab_server` I need to specify the username and password... so when I type `2200:lab_server:22` I noticed that it wouldn't accept command input like: `2200:user1@XX.XX.XX.XX:22` how can I specify the username too?

Comment: @kwagjj see updated answer

Comment: hmm.. I think your explanation is colliding with polym's explanation. First I think we should be clear on the terminology of the three players here: there are `mypc` `lab_desktop` `lab_server`. `mypc` is the computer that I would be typing in the commands.
I have understood your answer as : `mypc`'s port 2200 is connected with port 22 of `lab_server`.
but poylm's answer seems to say: `mypc` will login to `lab_desktop` and from there with `2200:lab_Server:22` command, any data received from port 22 of `lab_server` will be forwarded to port 2200 of `lab_desktop`.
which explanation is right?

Comment: @kwagjj My answer is correct.  -L specifies a local port forward, a local port is forwarded to a remote host.  Try it and let us know what happens

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but now there's another problem.. I've updated my question about this matter. Would be grateful if you could take a look at it

Comment: I've solved the problem. I now have a better understanding at this port forwarding thanks to you and polym. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

```
ssh -L 2200:lab_server:22 -vvv lab_desktop
```

will do the following:

It is being verbose on the maximum level (3), meaning it will print `debug level 3` information. An example is:

```
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
```

The `-L` lets you tunnel your data via the given port `2200` on your side `lab_desktop` to the `lab_server` on port `22`.

So if you connect to `lab_desktop` on port `2200`, you will receive data from `lab_server` on port `22`.

A good source about ssh port forwarding is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding#Local_Port_Forwarding).

Comment: almost got it ;)

Comment: hehe :D. I like you

Comment: :( I'm getting more and more confused... here's some more followup questions:

1. the order of the command is a little different from my original question. is this okay?

2. one problem I'm also facing is that when logging into `lab_desktop` and `lab_server` I need to speicify username and password. I think the command line won't be able to get the job done in one shot since I need to type in passwords and all that. How can I solve this?

Comment: 1. Well for most commands, it's always <cmd> <options> <essential arguments>, here ssh <options> <hostname>. Some or most programs will interpret anything after an <essential argument> as such. E.g. your `-L` might be seen as a command and therefore will produce you an error.

2. I think `sshpass` can help you there, it will give you the option to input your credentials.

Comment: @polym I think public key auth is probably more appropriate

Comment: yeah you are probably right :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ssh+lab_desktop+-L+2200%3Alab_server%3A22+-vvv

If the website is down you can run your own version

https://github.com/idank/explainshell

Extract from website

[image]